# Formula Phone Call Calculation

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm using the following statement to determine the correct prefix:

```
select *  
from [lcsCDR].[dbo].[Phones] c  
inner join [CallAnalysisDatabase].[dbo].[CallRates$] r  
    on r.Prefix COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = SUBSTRING(c.PhoneUri,1,LEN(r.Prefix))  
left join [CallAnalysisDatabase].[dbo].[CallRates$] r_anti  
    on r_anti.Prefix COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = SUBSTRING(c.PhoneUri,1,LEN(r_anti.Prefix))  
    and LEN(r_anti.Prefix) > LEN(r.Prefix)  
where r_anti.Prefix is null
```

Could you please give me an example for adding a formula integrated within this statement?

The 'Rate' table contains 2 calculation fields:

- start_rate
- rate_per_minute

A tables 'VoipDetails' and SessionDetails contains the folowing:

```
DATEDIFF(s, VoipDetails.SessionIdTime, SessionDetails.SessionEndTime)
```

If the correct prefix is found THEN use the following formule:

```
DATEDIFF(s, VoipDetails.SessionIdTime, SessionDetails.SessionEndTime))/60)*r.rate_per_minute)+start_rate)
```

Could you please give me an example for pl/sql ms sql server management studio?

Comment: Looks like this is related to a question I posted before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709323/what-is-a-good-approach-in-ms-sql-server-2008-to-join-on-a-best-match

Comment: Thanks, It is almost the same question, but a different syntax.  I'm not sure how to integrate my formula within the prefix select statement, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you want a Scalar Function in T-SQL.

Check this out:

[Create Function T-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: As I am not so familiar with Scalar Functions, could you please setup an example integrated in my prefix select statement?

Comment: Have a go first. Make a function, try and call it in a select, and then if you still need help I'll check it out.

Comment: isn't it possible to calculate the outcome directly in my select statement without using a function, i'm not familiair with this...